# Undefined variable while exporting in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting `undefined` while exporting variables in Node.js. Don't understand why it isn't working any help or suggestions?

index.js

```
var test = 10;
module.exports.test = test;
```

config.js (inside "files" folder)

```
var includes = require('../index.js');
console.log(includes.test);
```

Comment: Try module.exports = { test }

Comment: require('../index.js'); or require('./index.js'); ? I believe it is the relative path issue. It runs well on my local machine.

Comment: Try `console.log(includes)` and inspect what module you find

Comment: No repro ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/node-js-forked-8t6n54?file=/src/so-71151740/files/config.js

Comment: @Bergi I tried ```console.log(includes)``` and I am getting ```{}```

Comment: I think I found out why it's not working for me. I am newbie so I don't know if this is the reason and please correct me if I'm wrong. config.js is running before index.js and I think that's why I'm getting ```undefined```. I tried putting ```console.log(test)``` in index.js and in console I'm getting ```undefined``` first (that's console.log from config.js) and ```10``` second (that's console.log from index.js). In console I'm running ```node index.js```, this is the only explanations that I can think of. How can I fix it?

Comment: So you didn't share your complete code, and *index.js* actually has a `require('files/config.js');` at the top? Yes, that would definitely explain it, it's a circular dependency. See https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#cycles

Answer (score -1):

It's not `module.exports.test`. Try it like this.

```js
module.exports = test
```

Comment: i think you typo, it should :

module.exports = test